# Lubuntu 19.10 32-bit ISO?

Tags: lubuntu

They announced that they've change their plans and will release 32-bit images for Lubuntu 19.10. Are they released? Or when will they be released?

https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts

Comment: Please ask your favorite search engine: "When will Lubuntu 19.10 be released?"

Comment: I'm wondering if this question could be left open. It doesn't exactly fit "Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues." @Rinzwind, could they be releasing a 32-bit version without releasing a beta first? Wouldn't that be quite unusual? Plus I posted an answer that I hope explains what seems to be OP's misunderstanding of the linked blog.

Comment: The fact OP misunderstanding the statement does not invalidade the question. I was looking for a 32 bit ISO too, and this post answered me. Don't think it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

[Statement on 32-bit i386 packages](https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts)  has this:

> Thanks to the huge amount of feedback this weekend from gamers, Ubuntu
>   Studio, and the WINE community, we will change our plan and build
>   selected 32-bit i386 packages for Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 LTS.
>
> We will put in place a community process to determine which 32-bit
>   packages are needed to support legacy software ...

This in no way means there'll be a 32-bit release, just some packages to allow certain software to run.

So if you have a 32-bit CPU, 19.10 is not for you.

Indeed, http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/ and https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ don't list 32-bit versions for Lubuntu 19.10, only 64-bit.